# What is the difference between #define and creating a normal type?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, c-preprocessor

In C/C++, what is the difference between using `#define` [and `#ifndef` `#endif`] to create values, when you can easily do it with an `int` or `std::string` [C++] too?

```
#ifndef MYVAL
#define MYVAL(500)
#endif

//C++

cout << MYVAL << endl;

//C

printf(MYVAL);
```

---

```
//C++

int MYVAL = 500;
cout << MYVAL << endl;

//C
int MYVAL = 500;
printf(MYVAL);
```

Comment: Note that both code snippets for C don't compile.

Comment: The parentheses in the definition of `MYVAL` serve no purpose.

Comment: I think you mean that #define MYVAL(500) has two problems, first it has '500' as a macro parameter, which is illegal, if the name was intended to be a number, it should have been prefixed with something that was allowed like #define MYVAL(a500) would be okay, just like naming conventions elsewhere. Secondly, since there is nothing past the declaration of the macro and it's single parameter, it essentially does nothing, assuming you use it in it's proper way: you couldn't just MYVAL somewhere, you would have to put a parameter in there too (ie, MYVAL(some_param)),but replaces to an empty value!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before I jump into history, here's a brief understanding of the difference between the two.

Variables are, well, variables.  They take up space in the compiled program, and unless you mark them with `const` (which is a much later development than macros), they're mutable.

Macros, on the other hand, are **preprocessed**.  The compiler never sees the macro.  Instead, the macros are handled before compiling.  The precompiler goes through the code, finds every macro, and replaces it verbatim with the macro text.  This can be very powerful, somewhat useful, and fairly dangerous (since it's modifying code and never does any checking when doing so).

Also, macros can be set on the command line.  You can define as many things as you want when you are compiling, and if your code checks for that macro, it can behave differently.

Macros existed long before C++.  They have been useful for many things:

- You can use them very easily to represent constant expressions.  They can save space, because they don't require any variables (though the constant expression still needs to be compiled in somewhere), and they existed before the `const` specifier, so they were an easy way to maintain constant "variables" - the precompiler would replace all instances of MYVAR with 500.
- You can do all sorts of functions with them.  I actually never made any myself, because the benefits never seemed to outweigh the risks.  Macro functions that aren't carefully constructed can easily break your compile.  But I have used some predefined macro functions.
- #define macros are still used for many things

  - include guards (header files usually have a macro defined at the top, and check if it's defined to make sure they don't add it again),
  - TRUE and FALSE in C,
  - setting DEBUG mode so that code can behave differently for debugging and release.  As one simple example, assertions are functions that behave differently if the DEBUG macro is present.  (If it's not present, it returns completely empty code.)

In the limited case where you're simply using a macro to represent a constant expression, you're right - they're no longer needed for that.

Comment: People learning C or C++ should be taught that preprocessing is a separate phase from the subsequent semantic operations but not that “the compiler never sees the macro”. Preprocessing is a part of language translation (e.g., per C 2011 5.1.1.2), and it may be integrated into the compiler (as GCC does). This can produce effects such as intelligent error messages (that weave preprocessing effects with other information) or programs that fail to compile due to a later-phase semantic violation that is earlier in the source code than an earlier-phase preprocessing error (such as `#error`).

Answer (score 12):

Your assumptions are wrong. `#define` doesn't create "values", it creates *replacement text* in your source code. It has basically nothing to do with C or C++ at all.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that with the macros (#) the preprocessor does a search and replace on that symbol.  There is no type checking on the replace.

When you create a variable, it is typed and the compiler will do type checking where you use it.

C/C++ compilers are often thought of as 2-pass compilers.  The first pass is the preprocessor which does search and replace on macros.  The second pass is the actual compilation where the declared variables are created.

Macros are often used to create more complex expressions so the code doesn't have to be repeated more than once and so the syntax is more compact.  They are useful, but also more dangerous due to their 'blind' search and replace nature.  In addition, you can't step into a macro with a debugger so they can be harder to troubleshoot.

Also, macros do not obey any scoping rules.  `#define MYVAL(500)` will replace `MYVAL` with `500` even if it occurs in functions, global scope, class declarations, etc.  so you have to be more careful in that way.

Comment: Actually, macro expansion and execution of preprocessing directives is one of **eight** phases in translation of a C 2011 program (per clause 5.1.1.2). They are not necessarily performed in separate passes. E.g., GCC does preprocessing and subsequent compilation in a single pass.

Comment: Thanks @Eric Postpischil.  I was trying to keep it simple for the intended question.

Answer (score 2):

When you `#define` something, it will be blindly replaced whenever it's found in your code:

```
#define the_answer 42
/// ...

int the_answer = /* oops! */
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few important reasons why you shouldn't use #defines. For your questions in particular I would say, #define are plain text replacements and you can't limit the scope of the macro. i.e, you can't specify an access specifier or bind it to a namespace, so once you define the macros you can use them anywhere in the files where the define is included.

With 'const' variables you can have them bound in a scope

These could help : http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-vs-define.html

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/preprocessor-is-evil.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge difference:

a) `#define MYVAL 500`

This will create a macro. Each of its occurences in the source code will be replaced by its raw value by the preprocessor. It completely ignores the scope and you cannot change its value

b) `int MYVAL = 500;`

This is a regular variable that obeys scope rules, i. e. when declared inside a function, it cannot be seen outside it, it can be shadowed within another function, etc...

On the other hand, variables cannot be used in preprocesor conditions (`#if`, `#endif` blocks)

One last example:

```
#define MYVAL 500

int main() {
    int MYVAL = 10; // illegal, gets preprocessed as int 500 = 10;
}
```

Same with variable:

```
int MYVAL = 500

int main() {
    int MYVAL = 10; // legal, MYVAL now references local variable, ::MYVAL is the global variable
}
```